# Multithreaded programming C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am looking for a good book/article/reference on multithreaded programming in C++. I found few older threads where there are some recommendations. However, most of them are in Java. Does anyone know of anything strictly in C++?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a somewhat modern compiler, just creating threads is extremely simple with [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread). It's the synchronization between threads that can be tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a book by manning called: [C++ Concurrency in Action](http://www.manning.com/williams/) which looks very promising.
It should be available next month and it has a lot of C++ threading from how to create threads to advanced concurrency topic such as lock free collections (in C++!).

Answer (score 2):

A nice video tutorial up to date with C++11 here [MSDN](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Threads-and-Shared-Variables-in-C-11). It's not for beginners and will only be helpful with a recent compiler.

Answer (score 1):

An oldie but a goodie: O'Reilly's "Pthreads Programming" book. Examples are in C, which will work fine in a C++ program. If you're really looking for an OO approach, however, this probably won't cut it. I'd imagine there are more recent references but I found this to be a well written book when I read it years ago.