# Dividing data for multithreaded processing

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am trying to learn about multithreading and how to use it to perform tasks on a set of data in parallel. For example if I have a array of numbers that I want to perform a rather long operation on, I have created the following code to process it:

```
mutex mm;
int nums[] = {10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90};
int index = 0;

void threadProc()
{
    while (index != sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0])) //While != to end of array
    {
        mm.lock();
        int num = nums[index]; //Create local copy so we can unlock mutex for other threads
        index++;
        mm.unlock();
        cout << num + 2; //Replace with time-consuming function
    }
}

int main()
{
    //Create 2 threads
    thread t(threadProc);
    thread a(threadProc);
    t.join();
    a.join();
}
```

Since I am creating this code based off of what I seem logical, is this the proper way to do this? Of course I could add more threads based on the amount of hardware threads the CPU has, but I am going for the general idea here. If there are any good resources on this (preferably C++ oriented), I would be glad to hear about them. Thanks!

Comment: Learn about [OMP](http://openmp.org/mp-documents/omp-hands-on-SC08.pdf). It takes a lot of the hard work out of coding for parallel processing, and most of the time your code will be faster, more compact, more robust, and more readable for it. Highly recommended.

Comment: Ideally you'd cut the array in half and let the two threads work on each half entirely independently (no mutexes). Also, as you've written it, it's possible for one thread to try to be reading `index` (in the loop condition) while the other thread is writing to `index` (inside the mutex lock), which can be problematic.

Comment: @Floris This looks interesting, I have never heard of it. I will definitely look into it!

Comment: Is nums readonly? or other threads update it? If the latter is true, you can check the reader-writer lock, here

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read/write_lock_pattern

Comment: @JohnSmith Good point, I suppose I can make the mutex only for the `index++`

Comment: Since `index` is written by multiple threads, you must guard accesses to it, as it stand you have a race condition there. Make the loop a `while(true)` loop and check for remaining elements between the `mm.lock()` and `mm.unlock()`. BTW: using a scoped lock, you can bind the lock/unlock to the scope of an object, which correctly releases even if you throw an exception or return, making it one less thing to worry about. Otherwise, your code looks correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned years ago with OReilly's Pthread Programming book and I see it referenced here too [Multithreaded programming C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477049/multithreaded-programming-c)

Answer (score 2):

In general, you have two options: Thread-based parallelism or Task-based parallelism. The first is the most traditional approach and pthreads and OpenMP are a good examples of it. In the second alternative, you have one more abstraction level, where you see your parallel program as a set of tasks that are mapped to threads. A good reference to learn the model of computation is the chapter 27 of Introduction to Algorithms of Cormen (http://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/titles/content/9780262033848_sch_0001.pdf) and some tools to program are CilkPlus (http://cilkplus.org/), Threading Building Blocks (http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/), OpenMP Tasks(http://openmp.org/wp/), and Microsoft’s Task Parallel Library (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx).

Finally, you can read The Art of Multiprocessor Programming ([http://www.amazon.com/The-Multiprocessor-Programming-Maurice-Herlihy/dp/0123705916](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123705916))